# how to get the required nodes instead of all nodes in xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<table>
<tr> <th> colspan=3 **pencils** </th> </tr>
<tr> <td> camelin </td></tr>
<tr> <td> upsara </td></tr>
<tr> <th> colspan=3 **subjects** </th> </tr>
<tr> <td> Maths </td></tr>
<tr> <td> Physics </td></tr>
<tr> <td> Chemistry </td></tr>
<tr> <th> colspan=3 **books** </th></tr>
```

If node `tr` contains pencils then I want following tr nodes contains camelin and upsara. But I am getting all camelin,upsara,maths,physics combiningly.

Similarly if `tr` contains subjects then I want following nodes contains maths  physics and chemistry.
i want the text after pencils I mean the next two nodes are related to pencils information.
I want the text between colspans by checking the condition in it.And one more thing is the count of  is dynamic not static.

Comment: Do you want to get all TD between TH? Please clarify logic little bit more.
Do you want values after **pencils** but before next TH (**subjects**)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
It returns first 2 TD elements after pencils or subjects.

```
/table/tr[contains(th/text(), 'pencils')]/following-sibling::tr[position()<3]/td/text()
/table/tr[contains(th/text(), 'subjects')]/following-sibling::tr[position()<3]/td/text()
```